# Find the min and max of each nested list in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to find the min and max of each list in a nested list, and the index of when the min or max occurred:

So that, for example:

```
l=[[5,6,7][6,10,9,6][2,3,1]]
```

Becomes:

```
maxl=[7,10,3]
indexl=[2,1,2]
```

I've tried this and it seems to get me the max list (no indexes yet) but not for min- does anyone know how best to do this?

```
maxHap=[]
for subL in happiness1:
    maxHap.append(max(subL))
print(maxHap)

minHap=[]
for subL in happiness1:
    minHap.append(min(subL))
print(minHap)
```

Thank you from a newbie

Comment: Are you open to using an additional dependency like numpy?

Comment: This should actually work. What results do you get?

Comment: The max list is filled but the min list just returns a list of spaces, which is incorrect

Comment: Got it working! But thanks

Comment: Why is the expected output for "l=[[5,6,7][6,10,9,6][2,3,1]]", "maxl=[7,10,3] and indexl=[2,1,2]"? Shouldn't it be (7, 10, 3) and (2, 1, **1**) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `index` to get the index of a value of a list:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

```
maxl = []
indexl = []
for inner_list in l:
    max_value = max(inner_list)
    maxl.append(max(max_value))
    indexl.append(inner_list.index(max_value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Other option:

```
l=[[5,6,7],[6,10,9,6],[2,3,1]]

maxs = [ max(s) for s in l ] #=> [7, 10, 3]
max_idxs = [ s.index(max(s)) for s in l ] #=> [2, 1, 1]
mins = [ min(s) for s in l ] #=> [5, 6, 1]
mins_idxs = [ s.index(min(s)) for s in l ] #=> [0, 0, 2]
```

---

Or you can store the results into an array of dict, one liner:

```
mapp = map(lambda x: {'max': max(x), 'max_idxs': x.index(max(x)), 'min': min(x), 'min_idxs': x.index(min(x)) }, l)

for k in mapp:
  print(k)

#=> {'max': 7, 'max_idxs': 2, 'min': 5, 'min_idxs': 0}
#=> {'max': 10, 'max_idxs': 1, 'min': 6, 'min_idxs': 0}
#=> {'max': 3, 'max_idxs': 1, 'min': 1, 'min_idxs': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following one-liner:

```
l=[[5,6,7],[6,10,9,6],[2,3,1]]
maxL, index = zip(*[(max(subList), subList.index(max(subList))) for subList in l])
print(maxL) # will output (7, 10, 3)
print(index) # will output (2, 1, 1)
```